# Use webpack with jade-loader without explicitly requiring assets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, pug, webpack

I am trying to use Webpack jade-loader in combination with html-loader to be able to omit requires in jade templates + use a path relative to a certain folder. I have tried a few things, none of them worked.

By default jade-loader works when using `img(src=require("../../../../assets/images/imac.png") alt="computer")`, with the following webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './app/app.js'
  ],
  context: path.resolve(__dirname + "/client"),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {

    // placed here so we know that it is done before transpiling
    preLoaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: "eslint-loader", exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.config\.js/, /\.conf\.js/ ] }
    ],

    loaders: [
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
      { test: /\.jade$/, loader: 'jade-loader' },
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css!less' },
      { test: /\.css/, loader: 'style!css' },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/, loader: 'file' },
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel?stage=1', exclude: [/client\/lib/, /node_modules/, /\.spec\.js/] }
    ]
  },

  eslint: {
    configFile: './.eslintrc'
  }
};
```

If I add the html-loader (`{ test: /\.jade$/, loader: 'html-loader!jade-loader' }`) which is supposed to require sources by default, I keep getting the 'Error: Module not found'. The console logs all the paths that it tried, all relative to the current working file.

I tried to give it some context, with `context: path.resolve(__dirname + "/client")`. It didn't work either.
I also tried to combine with the raw loader: `raw-loader!html-loader!jade-loader`. I don't get the error but the wepback output that is served is not my app at all, but instead something along the lines of:
var jade = require(/......) ....

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same Problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-html-loader worked for me:

```
module.exports = {
// your config settings ... 
     module: [
     //your modules... 
         loaders: [{
             include: /\.jade/,
             loader: 'pug-html-loader'
         }]
    ] 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you want. My need is to load a template from a directive (component in 1.5)

```
angular.module('app').component('myComponent', {
  bindings: {},
  template: require('./mytemplate.jade')()
});
```

You can to note that I'm invoking the returned function.